# Ломается верстка формы при оборачивании в div class="row"

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы форма находилась по горизонтальному и вертикальному центру. При попытке засунуть форму в `<div class="row"></div>` съезжает верстка. Не могу понять что не так. Вроде делаю все по документации Bootstrap.
Пример на [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/r8mtoZHfRC)

Comment: а что значит "съезжает"? как должно быть?

Comment: съезжает в том плане, что поля и лейблы сжимает с боков

Comment: @DamirFelix а как вы хотите? Чтобы поля были на всю ширину экрана?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Авторизация</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inputLogin" class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Логин</label>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Введите логин" required autofocus>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-form-label col-3 text-right">Пароль</label>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Введите пароль">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="inputCheck">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inputCheck">Запомнить меня</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Войти</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Дело не в row - просто Вы зачем-то упаковали лейблы и поля в узкие колонки для больших экранов (col-lg-1, col-lg-3). На маленьких экранах всё ок, а на больших потому и сжимает.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Авторизация</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inputLogin" class="col-form-label col-lg-1 text-lg-right">Логин</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Введите логин" required autofocus>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-form-label col-lg-1 text-lg-right">Пароль</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Введите пароль">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="inputCheck">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inputCheck">Запомнить меня</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Войти</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: мне нужно чтобы лейбл и инпут в одном блоке располагались на одной строке

Comment: @DamirFelix, ну и в чём проблема? задаёте им колонки, чтобы в сумме не больше 12-ти получалось: я обновил ответ - сделал 3 и 9 для примера